# Why webpack fails to compile when nested package.json exists

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

Here project structure

```
src/
--ui/
--lib/
----async-store/
------create-inject-reducer-hoc.jsx
------package.json <<=== this package.json
--package.json
--index.js
--webpack.config.js
```

Project fails to build with error:

```
ERROR in ./lib/async-store/create-inject-reducer-hoc.jsx
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: \src\lib\async-store\create-inject-reducer-hoc.jsx: Unexpected token (34:11)

  32 |     }, [])
  33 |
> 34 |     return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
     |            ^
  35 |   }
  36 |   return memo(InjectedState)
  37 | }
```

Here webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  }
}
```

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "ssr": false }]
    ]
}
```

ACTIONS:
**If i remove nested package.json in `lib/async-store/` project will build successfully**

QUESTION:
**What relationship with webpack build process and nested package.json?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be due to how babel is configured. Anything with a `package.json` file is considered a separate package, or module. And since you have two `package.json` files, you essentially have a *monorepo*.

Because you are using a `.babelrc` config file, the following, from https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration, will apply to you:

> Babel loads `.babelrc` [...] files by searching up the directory structure [...]. Searching will stop once a directory containing a `package.json` is found, so a relative config only applies within a single package. [...] `.babelrc` files only apply to files within their own package

Without further configuration, webpack, using babel-loader, will come across your folder containing the `package.json` file, and won't apply any transforms to it. Because of this, it complains about the JSX it sees, since it's not being compiled.

There are a couple solutions to this, one of which you already mentioned:

1. Remove the nested `package.json` file. Why do you need it, anyway?
2. Switch from a `.babelrc` config file to a `babel.config.js` config file. Why? There are more details at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos, but the important bit is that babel will set up a `babel.config.js` as the root config, which "sub-packages" will use.

   You can see how to configure your `babel.config.js` file at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#babelconfigjs.